# unauthorized: authentication required - trying to pull or run a public image

Tags: r, docker

I'm trying to follow along [this](https://ropenscilabs.github.io/r-docker-tutorial/02-Launching-Docker.html) blog about using Docker with R.

I followed basic Docker set up steps and am able to run the hello world image.

I'm on a old 2009 Mac and had to use Docker Toolbox.

I'm in a place with weak internet connection and am using a personal hotspot.

Each time I try to run `docker run --rm -p 8787:8787 rocker/verse` I wait for a few minutes and see a downloading message, then I get a message "docker: unauthorized: authentication required."

I found [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio/) separate documentation which advised me to add a password:

```
docker run --rm -p 8787:8787 -e PASSWORD=blah rocker/rstudio
```

But I got the same result "docker: unauthorized: authentication required."

I did some Google searching and found some posts both here on SO and on Github but was unable to identify what is causing this error in my specific case.

I suspect my weak internet connection might have something to do with it since I seem to be able to download for about 10 or 15 minutes before seeing this message.

Here is Docker info:

```
Macs-MacBook:~ macuser$ docker info
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 2
Server Version: 18.09.6
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: bb71b10fd8f58240ca47fbb579b9d1028eea7c84
runc version: 2b18fe1d885ee5083ef9f0838fee39b62d653e30
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.14.116-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 18.09.6 (TCL 8.2.1)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.951GiB
Name: default
ID: XMCE:OBLV:CKEX:EGIB:PHQ7:MLHF:ZJSA:PGYN:OIMM:JI67:ETCI:JKBH
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Does anyone know where I can look to next in order to be able to pull and or run the rocker image?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever sort this out?

Comment: I did, and I honestly cannot remember what I changed. Sorry